# Detecting UIButton in frame

Tags: ios

I have a method that is called once in a while. it creates a button and gives it a frame and adds it on the self.view. The problem is that I don't want these buttons to overlap, so I am using a counter (integer) to keep the count of how many there are. Sometimes the counter goes wrong of +-1 and two buttons appear overlapping.

This is the code:

in my .h

```
int CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices;
```

in the .m

```
- (void) browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

NSLog(@"%@", peerID.description);

CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices = CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices + 1;

NSArray *keys = [BluetoothDeviceDictionary allKeys];
for (NSUInteger k = keys.count; k > 0; k--) {
    MCPeerID *key = keys[k - 1];
    UIButton *btn = BluetoothDeviceDictionary[key];
    if ([key.displayName isEqualToString:peerID.displayName]) {
        [btn removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"REMOVE DOUBLE");
        CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices--;
        [BluetoothDeviceDictionary removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
}

if (CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices == 1) {
BluetoothDeviceButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, -200, 55,55)];
}else if (CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices == 2){
    BluetoothDeviceButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, -200, 55,55)];
}else if (CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices == 3){
    BluetoothDeviceButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, -125, 55,55)];
}else if (CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices == 4){
    BluetoothDeviceButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, -125, 55,55)];
}
```

Is there a better way to detect this?

Comment: Why not use the count of the dict?

Comment: Your if statements don't look specific at first glance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use upper case variable and/or property names.
2. Change `CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices = CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices + 1;` to `countNumberOfBluetoothDevices++;`
3. Use `[keys count]` instead of `keys.count`.
4. The -200 in `CGRectMake(130, -200, 55,55)];` is very strange an looks like you have some issues with your view hierarchy. Why is it negative?
5. Instead of this

   ```
   NSArray *keys = [BluetoothDeviceDictionary allKeys];
   for (NSUInteger k = keys.count; k > 0; k--) {
       MCPeerID *key = keys[k - 1];
       ...
   }
   ```

I would do

```
    for (MCPeerID *key in [bluetoothDeviceDictionary allKeys]) {
        ...
    }
```